# How to get DriverDate in Readable format (mm-dd-yyyy) in powershell

Tags: powershell, date, format

I am using below command in powershell to get driver version and driver date :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver |?{$_.DeviceName -ne $null}|select DeviceName,DriverVersion,DriverDate |export-csv -path DeviceDriverVersion.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

However, for `DriverDate`, I am getting date in such format "20060621000000.******+***"  need to convert it into (mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: "20060621000000.******+***" -replace '^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*', '$2-$3-$1'

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article from MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richmac/2011/07/21/wmi-date-formats-powershell-to-the-rescue/), `ConvertToDateTime` from `Win32_OperatingSystem` could be used for parsing this date/time string, like:

```
$os = Get-WmiObject –Class Win32_OperatingSystem
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver `
    |?{$_.DeviceName -ne $null}`
    |select DeviceName,DriverVersion,@{Label="DriverDate";Expression={$os.ConvertToDateTime($_.DriverDate).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")}}`
    |export-csv -path DeviceDriverVersion.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Can you please provide script to get Application Name & Version in excel